# How do I make FFmpeg C++ code not output error messages?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm decoding video using FFmpeg's C++ library like this:

```
AVPacket* avPacket = av_packet_alloc();
if (!avPacket) std::cout << "av packet error" << std::endl;
int result = avcodec_send_packet(avCodecContext, avPacket);
    if (!result) {
        for ( ; !result ; ) {
            result = avcodec_receive_frame(avCodecContext, avFrame);
            if (!result) {
            ...
```

It works, but sometimes FFmpeg encounters problematic frames and emits the following:

```
[h264 @ 0x7fd3bc2c4b00] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7fd3bc2c4b00] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7fd3bc2c4b00] no frame!
```

Is it possible to turn off these messages? I don't see any obvious way to do it.

Comment: You can redirect standard error output somewhere and discard it.

Comment: "Is it possible to turn off these messages?" - Certainly. Just edit the code of the library and remove them. Then recompile it and use/distribute the modified library with your application.

Comment: Command-line FFmpeg allows you to control messages with the `-loglevel` parameter. The C++ interface probably has a way to do it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need is `av_log_get_level` and `av_log_set_level`.
Please check these out: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__log.html#gae8ada5cc5722548d8698650b05207904

Answer (score 4):

In my code, I use `av_log_set_callback()` to redirect output messages to my own log file, so I can filter out unwanted messages before writing them to the log.